# access violation inside ADODB recordset Close

Tags: c++, com, ado

Still trying to figure out what is happening with ADODB's connections and why a certain crash is occuring.

The problem was that we had a memory leak in our code:

```
void getDetailConfig()
{
    m_displayConf = new TestDetailDisplayCfg(); 
}
```

This function is called often so a basic memory leak.
Fixed it with a unique pointer

```
void getDetailConfig()
{
    m_displayConf = std::make_unique<TestDetailDisplayCfg>();
}
```

Yay party, but now an acces violation started to happen inside ADODB's Recordset15::Close.

```
inline HRESULT Recordset15::Close ( ) {
    HRESULT _hr = raw_Close();
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _hr;
}
```

> Unhandled exception at 0x679E653F (msado15.dll) in LaneControl.exe:
>   0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user
>   callback.

So calling all destructors the right way caused a new issue, there are recordset's opened and closed somewhere.

After debugging it turns out that getDetailConfig is called from two different threads.

**Thread1**

```
void updateIconStatus()
{
    getDetailConfig();
}
```

[image: thread1]

Thread ID 5bA8

**Thread2**

```
void CVTSDetailDisplay::setCurrentTestIconStatus(int status)
{
    m_CurrentDialog->getDetailConfig();
}
```

[image: thread2]

Thread ID 6A4C

So these 2 threads call getDetailConfig where a recordset is closed which was opened on another thread and COM objects are Released and what not.

Is that a problem that you can't close ADO recordsets on another thread? Is it more a race condition?
What is going wrong here at ADODB's level?

Comment: 0xC000041D does not actually have that much to do with ADODB.  It can occur in a 32-bit app that runs on a 64-bit version of Windows.  There was *another* exception before this one that got thrown in a windows message handler (aka WndProc, aka "user callback").  Such an exception is quite difficult to handle correctly since the callback started in the 64-bit window manager and it can't unwind the stack properly through these layers.  Focus on seeing that first mishap, that's where it started to fall apart.  Force the debugger to stop on the "first chance exception"

Comment: Fwiw, ADODB is not thread-safe.  You have to marshal the interface pointer, typically most easily done [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/when-to-use-the-global-interface-table).

Comment: I would basically think that the object has been tried to be released twice (for the reason described in my answer), AKA "double-delete", so the second release indeed failed as the object was already no longer valid. And indeed, possible non-thread-safety of ADODB (which I don't know much about) can only add another injury to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think it is a race condition.

If the `getDetailConfig()` function was already called before, and then both threads call the `getDetailConfig()`, this can result in both threads calling the destructor (of the object which was there before) simultaneously (`std::unique_ptr` is not inherently thread-safe AFAIK).

You'd then need to ensure critical section for the exchange of the pointers, for example adding `std::mutex m_mutex;` as a member of your class (ideally to the first place in the members list so it remains valid longer than the `m_displayConf` member) and then adding

```
void getDetailConfig()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    m_displayConf = std::make_unique<TestDetailDisplayCfg>();
}
```

to make sure the exchange is locked between threads.